# FTP download stops at file #146

Tags: java

I wrote this class (from examples) to download the header of all the files contained in a remote FTP folder. It works well, but when it approaches to download the file #146 it stops with a NullPointException. The file #146 exists and I can download it as a single file actually.

In the method remotePathLong contains all the remote folders written in a single line and spaced with the space character.

```
public void downloadHeader(String remotePathLong, String destPath, int bytes) {

    String remotePath;
    FTPFile[] fileList;
    String[] fileNameList;

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftpClient.connect(server);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        int indice = 0;
        int iP = 1;
        File downloadFile;
        String destFile;
        String remoteFile;
        byte[] bytesArray;
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((remotePath = getPath(remotePathLong, iP)) != null) {
            System.out.println("Loading file list from the server.....");
            fileNameList = ftpClient.listNames(remotePath);
            for (String file : fileNameList) {
                indice += 1;
                System.out.println(indice + " - Downloading: " + file);

                //Select files
                destFile = destPath.concat(file);

                downloadFile = new File(destFile);
                outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile));

                //Download remote file (from ftp)
                remoteFile = remotePath.concat(file);

                inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remoteFile);
                bytesArray = new byte[bytes];
                bytesRead = inputStream.read(bytesArray);
                outputStream.write(bytesArray);

                //Save into file

                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
                iP += 1;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
    } final{
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex1) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex1.getMessage());
        }
}
```

when it reaches bytesRead = inputStream.read(bytesArray), at the iteration #146 it gives the error. But if at the same iteration i reinitialize the connection it works.
Does anybody have a suggestion please?

Comment: Reinitialize the connection at iteration #146? (only half-joking here)

Comment: Link to the example, please?

Comment: if the problem is consistent, then check file permissions

Comment: for example: user="";pass="";server=data-out.unavco.org;remotePathLong=/pub/rinex/obs/2000/273/;bytes=1024;destPath="C:/Users/Name/Documents". Everything looks consistent. If I copy and paste the link it is going to download for the file #146 it downloads it. I also have the permission because everything is public.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your connection times out due to a network traffic or a file size that happens to be 146th.
Can you print the 146th file name and check its size. Also you can increase the FTP connection timeout period

```
ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(300); // set timeout to 5 minutes
```

Comment: the file is hnps2730.00d.Z with a file size of 308kB. It is not different in size from the previous ones. Anyway I think something wrong happens with the connection. In fact, if I force at the #146th download to download one of the previous files it does not do it. I tried to increse the timeout also to very big values, but nothing change.

Comment: I would try to get a reply after each file file transfer (something like client.getReplyString()  And also can you netstat -an |grep <your ftp port> to see if the coinnection is alive when the error happens?

Comment: Thus I've put the getReplyString() after each inputStream.read(bytesArray). It always say:
150-Accepted data connection
150 xx.x kbytes to download
But for the file #146 it says:
226-File successfully transferred
226 0.000 seconds (measured here), 315.55 Mbytes per second
but a NullPointerException is generated.

Netsat prints:
TCP address:port prissy:ftp ESTABLISHED

Comment: do you think your FTp hit 2Gb in total files transferred? You could try to split your ftp in two or three pieces and open and close ftp connection for each portion. if it works you may have a size limitation for a single ftp transfer

Comment: Probably it is like you said. I don't know if there is a limitation actually but now it is working!!! I'm cathing the null pointer exception and initializing the connection.